# org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled

Tags: primefaces

I have this problem, and I don't understand why...I used it all the time in this way

```
<p:dataTable id="datatable"  var="ligne" value="#{ficheMB.lignes}"
selection="#{ficheMB.selectedLignes}" rowKey="#{ligne.id}" >
                        
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
                    
    <p:column headerText="Article">
        <h:outputText value="#{ligne.article.nom}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Tarif">
        <h:outputText value="#{ligne.article.tarif}" />
    </p:column>
```

this is the error

```
javax.faces.FacesException: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled.
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getRowKeyFromModel(DataTable.java:1409)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:1244)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRows(DataTableRenderer.java:1184)
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Looks like you've upgraded. Did you follow the migration guide?

Comment: I resolved the problem thank you...